# Best way to live stream video from java server to android client?

Tags: java, vlc, multicast, live-streaming, vlcj

I've been searching the **best way to live stream PC's screen from Java server to Android client** since few days now but I can't find an other way to *TCP* socket.
I want to stream **from PC to Android** client.

For now I just send images (frames) through *TCP* sockets. It works fine but here are the cons:

- large bandwidth consumption (unicast through multiple clients)
- serveral seconds shift between server and client
- low frame rate

I tried with *UDP* socket but how to deal with maximum size packet of 64Ko ?
The best solution will be *UDP* with **multicast** but I read some problems about it on Android, that is device dependent.

*Thanks in advance for your answers !*

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally succeed to **stream my PC's screen through RTP** on Java server

### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean found = new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    System.out.println(found);
    System.out.println(LibVlc.INSTANCE.libvlc_get_version()); 

    String media = "screen://";
    String options = formatRtpStream("230.0.0.1", 5555);

    System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
    CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

    // Creating a JFrame to display stream (duplicate)
    JFrame f = new JFrame("vlcj duplicate output test");
    f.add(canvas);
    f.setSize(800, 600);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media,
        options,
        ":no-sout-rtp-sap",
        ":no-sout-standard-sap",
        ":sout-all",
        ":sout-keep"
    );

    // Don't exit
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}

private static String formatRtpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
    sb.append(":sout=");
    // Transcode with codec (mp4v here), 30 FPS, not resized (scale 1), audio disabled (only video).
    sb.append("#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,fps=30,scale=1,noaudio}");
    // Creating RTP address
    sb.append(":rtp{dst=");
    sb.append(serverAddress);
    sb.append(",port=");
    sb.append(serverPort);
    // Encapsulation method used for the resulting stream, this option has to be set.
    sb.append(",mux=ts}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

### Display resulting stream in a window:

You can replace this:

```
sb.append(":rtp{dst=");
sb.append(",mux=ts}");
```

By this:

```
sb.append(":duplicate{dst=display,dst=rtp{dst=");
sb.append(",mux=ts}}");
```

This way you will be able to see the resulting stream.

---

### Some interesting links:

- [VLC User Guide](http://www.tldp.org/REF/VLC-User-Guide/x1110.html)
- [How to stream using VLC](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html)